# Why does the result mismatch variant type

Tags: excel, vba

## Dim Roles As Variant is a compile error even though it is a variant type. Type mismatch. Please specify an array or user-defined type. Why does the result look like this?

```
Sub CreateRotatingRolesAndGroups()
    Dim TotalParticipants As Integer
    Dim Participants() As String
    Dim Roles() As Variant
    Dim Groups() As String
    Dim CurrentRound As Integer
    Dim GroupSize As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim OutputRow As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' グループのサイズと総参加者数を設定
    GroupSize = 4
    TotalParticipants = 40 ' A組とB組合わせた参加者数

    ' 役割の配列を作成
    Roles = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

    ' 参加者の名前を設定
    ReDim Participants(1 To TotalParticipants)
    For i = 1 To TotalParticipants
        Participants(i) = "参加者" & i
    Next i

    ' グループ数を計算
    ReDim Groups(1 To TotalParticipants)
    For i = 1 To TotalParticipants
        Groups(i) = "グループ" & (i - 1) \ GroupSize + 1
    Next i

    ' 新しいワークシートを作成
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

    ' 各ラウンドでのグループと役割を割り当てる
    OutputRow = 1
    CurrentRound = 1
    Do
        If CurrentRound >= 1 And CurrentRound <= 4 Then
            ' 1回目から4回目は同じ組の中からグループ分け
            Call ShuffleArray(Groups)
        ElseIf CurrentRound >= 5 And CurrentRound <= 8 Then
            ' 5回目から8回目はA組、B組から2名ずつをランダムに選択
            Call RandomlySelectFromGroups(Groups, 2, "A")
            Call RandomlySelectFromGroups(Groups, 2, "B")
        Else
            ' 9回目以降はランダムにグループ分け
            Call ShuffleArray(Groups)
        End If

        ' グループと役割をシャッフル
        Call ShuffleArray(Groups)
        Call ShuffleArray(Roles)

        ' グループと役割をワークシートに書き込む
        For i = 1 To TotalParticipants
            ws.Cells(OutputRow, 1).Value = Participants(i)
            ws.Cells(OutputRow, 2).Value = Groups(i)
            ws.Cells(OutputRow, 3).Value = Roles(i Mod 4)
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Next i

        CurrentRound = CurrentRound + 1
    Loop Until CurrentRound > 12 ' 12回分の割り当てを行う
End Sub

Sub ShuffleArray(ByRef Arr() As Variant)
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ' Fisher-Yates シャッフルアルゴリズムを使用
    For i = UBound(Arr) To LBound(Arr) Step -1
        j = Int((i - LBound(Arr) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(Arr))
        Temp = Arr(i)
        Arr(i) = Arr(j)
        Arr(j) = Temp
    Next i
End Sub

Sub RandomlySelectFromGroups(ByRef Groups() As String, ByVal Count As Integer, ByVal GroupPrefix As String)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim GroupIndices() As Integer
    Dim AvailableGroupIndices() As Integer

    ReDim GroupIndices(1 To UBound(Groups))
    ReDim AvailableGroupIndices(1 To UBound(Groups))

    ' GroupPrefix に一致するグループのインデックスを取得
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Groups)
        If Left(Groups(i), Len(GroupPrefix)) = GroupPrefix Then
            j = j + 1
            GroupIndices(j) = i
        End If
    Next i

    ' 利用可能なグループのインデックスを初期化
    For i = 1 To UBound(Groups)
        AvailableGroupIndices(i) = i
    Next i

    ' GroupIndices からランダムに Count 個のグループを選択
    For i = 1 To Count
        j = Int((UBound(GroupIndices) - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        Groups(GroupIndices(j)) = "Selected"
        GroupIndices(j) = GroupIndices(UBound(GroupIndices))
        ReDim Preserve GroupIndices(1 To UBound(GroupIndices) - 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The only mismatch I see is when you pass `Groups` to the `ShuffleArray` routine, since `Groups` is a `String` array and your routine expects a `Variant` one.

Comment: There is no type mismatch between how you declare `Roles` and `Roles = Array("A","B","C","D")`. Please provide a [mcve] with an emphasis on minimal.

Comment: If you change ShuffleArray this way `Sub ShuffleArray(ByRef Arr)`, it passes that part. I encountered another issue with `Groups(GroupIndices(j)) = "Selected"` in RandomlySelectedGroups due to the way you filled in GroupIndices (with that If) so you'll have to catch that since Groups' lower bound starts at 1, not 0 which GroupIndices will return if nothing's filled in.